# Graphing polar coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, polar-coordinates

i) f(r,θ) = (rcosθ,rsinθ)

Sketch the image of f of the set S=[1,2]×[0,π].

ii) sketch $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$

for the set $ S = \{(x, y) : x^2 + y^2 < a^2;\; x,y\ge 0\}$

I have found Df matrix and its det of the jacobian matrix but not sure if it helps me to sketch the graph. Is there an app for two-dimension polar coordinates graph? And how would i graph this if i have to do it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite elementary and you don't need calculus: for each fixed $r\in[1,2]$, you obtain  the semi-circle centred at the origin with radius $r$, in the upper semi-plane above the $x$-axis. Hence, varying $r$, you obtain the semi-annulus between the circles with radii $1$ and $2$, located in the upper semi-plane.

*Edit*:

For question ii), use  polar coordinates: the domain of $f$ is the set of points $(x,y)$ with polar coordinates $r,\theta$ such  that $0\le r <a$ and $0\le \theta\le\frac\pi 2$. 
Now
$$f(x,y)=\bigl(r^2(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta), 2r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\bigr)=r^2(\cos2\theta, \sin2\theta).$$
Further, $0\le 2\theta\le \pi$ and $0\le r^2<a^2$. So we obtain the open semi-circle in the upper semi-plane with radius $a^2$.

Comment: got it, thank you, how about something like $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ for the set$ S = {(x, y) : x^2 + y^2 < a^2; x,y>= 0}$ it is part of the same question but wouldn't this then be 4-dimesnional? how can i graph that

Comment: i have added it to the question btw sorry

Comment: There's no reason to be $4$-dimensional (except i you want to see the domain and the codomain simultaneously). The image  will be a domain in the plane.